# rails associations: user must exists issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, associations

I'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/fmyvWz5TUWg?list=LL&t=8801) and I'm working on an app where each user has it's own list of plants. So two tables:

- Table A : **PLANTS** : plant_name:string, temp:float, humidity:float, ...
- Table B: **Devise Users**: default params from [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise).

Originally the table PLANTS didn't have a column to show that a plant was created by the user with id. So I added that using the following steps:

- In **models/plant.rb** I added the following: `belongs_to :user`
- In **models/user.rb** I added the following `has_many :plants`
- In **GitBash**: `rails g migration add_created_by_to_plants created_by:integer:index`
- Then push migration in **GitBash**: `rails db:migrate`

So now the schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_27_111702) do
  #Table Plants
  create_table "plants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "plant_name"
    t.float "temperature"
    t.float "humidity"
    t.float "water"
    t.string "light"
    t.string "soil"
    t.string "location"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "created_by"
    t.index ["created_by"], name: "index_plants_on_created_by"
  end

  #Table User Accounts
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
end
```

I changed the front-end when creating a new plant so that it can submit a **created by user id** in the form:

```
<%= form.number_field :created_by, id: :plant_created_by, class:"form-control", value: current_user.id, type: :hidden %>
```

FYI, this shows the correct ID from the user that tries to create a new Plant and the application works as expected until the 2:42:00 on the tutorial! (Should get user must exists error and I do)

---

Now is the part where i have the error:

Because the `created_by` was created after, I have to let my `controllers/plants_controller.rb` know that it should allow this parameter to be passed (2:43:00)

- add the new parameter in the `def plant_params`:

```
def plant_params
      params.require(:plant).permit(:plant_name, :temperature, :humidity, :water, :light, :soil, :location, :created_by)
end
```

But when I try to add a new plant, I still get User must exist on the front end, and the terminal looks like this:

```
Started POST "/plants" for ::1 at 2021-04-27 15:34:18 +0300
Processing by PlantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "plant"=>{"plant_name"=>"oregano", "temperature"=>"50", "humidity"=>"20.5", "water"=
>"150", "light"=>"Partial Shade", "soil"=>"Any", "location"=>"Anywhere", "created_by"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create Plant"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering plants/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/plants/_form.html.erb:43
  Rendered plants/_form.html.erb (Duration: 5.7ms | Allocations: 1809)
  Rendered plants/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.6ms | Allocations: 1892)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered home/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 123)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 64.9ms | Allocations: 6287)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 68ms (Views: 65.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 8046)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is just some simple confusion here.

When you type `belongs_to :user` rails assumes (by convention) that the table has a `user_id` column and that this is to be used for the association of `Plant` -> `User`.

Due to the fact that rails infers convention and because `plant.attributes['user_id'] #=> nil`, when the rails looks for the "User" to exist it is actually querying for

```
SELECT 
  "users".*
FROM 
  "users" 
WHERE 
  "users"."id" IS NULL
```

Which obviously does not exist.

In your case though the column you want to associate by is called `created_by`. There is no way for rails to know this by default but you can tell the association about this deviation from convention.

```
class Plant < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'created_by'
end
```

Here we are telling rails that the association is called `user` but we want to use the `created_by` column (attribute) to associate the records.

That being said I think the `plant.user` is a bit awkward to read, instead we can make the association name `creator` with a few minor changes to the above.

```
class Plant < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: 'created_by', class_name: 'User'
end
```

Now the association is called `creator` but we needed to tell rails that `creator` is of the class `User` so that it knows what table to join to and what model to instantiate when it returns the object.

Now you have `plant.creator #=> <#User ...>` which in my opinion is a much more natural read.

Additional similar modifications will need to be made to the `has_many` association.

Documentation:
[belongs_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)
[has_many](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)